# How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?

Tags: password, sudo

On one particular machine I often need to run `sudo` commands every now and then.
I am fine with entering password on `sudo` in most of the cases.

However there are **three `sudo` commands** I want to run **without entering password**:

- `sudo reboot`
- `sudo shutdown -r now`
- `sudo shutdown -P now`

How can I exclude these commands from password protection to `sudo`?

Comment: Similar to [How to allow execution without using the sudo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-using-the-sudo)

Answer (score 367, accepted):

### Use the `NOPASSWD` directive

You can use the `NOPASSWD` directive in your [`/etc/sudoers` file](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html).

If your user is called `user` and your host is called `host` you could add these lines to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

This will allow the user `user` to run the desired commands on `host` without entering a password. All other [`sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)ed commands will still require a password.

The commands specified in the `sudoers` file *must* be fully qualified (i.e. using the absolute path to the command to run) as described in the [`sudoers` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html). Providing a relative path is considered a syntax error.

If the command ends with a trailing `/` character and points to a directory, the user will be able to run any command in that directory (but not in any sub-directories therein). In the following example, the user `user` can run any command in the directory `/home/someuser/bin/`:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /home/someuser/bin/
```

**Note:** Always use the command [`visudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) to edit the `sudoers` file to make sure you do not lock yourself out of the system – just in case you accidentally write something incorrect to the `sudoers` file. `visudo` will save your modified file to a temporary location and will *only* overwrite the real `sudoers` file if the modified file can be parsed without errors.

### Using `/etc/sudoers.d` instead of modifying `/etc/sudoers`

As an alternative to editing the `/etc/sudoers` file, you could add the two lines to a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/shutdown`. This is an elegant way of separating different changes to the `sudo` rights and also leaves the original `sudoers` file untouched for easier upgrades.

**Note:** Again, you should use the command [`visudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/visudo.8.html) to edit the file to make sure you do not lock yourself out of the system:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
```

This also automatically ensures that the owner and permissions of the new file is set correctly.

### If `sudoers` is messed up

If you did not use `visudo` to edit your files and then accidentally messed up `/etc/sudoers` or messed up a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` then you will be locked out of `sudo`.

The solution could be to fix the files using [`pkexec`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) which is an alternative to `sudo`.

To fix `/etc/sudoers`:

```
pkexec visudo
```

To fix `/etc/sudoers.d/shutdown`:

```
pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
```

If the ownership and/or permissions are incorrect for any `sudoers` file, the file will be ignored by `sudo` so you might also find yourself locked out in this situation. Again, you can use `pkexec` to fix this.

The correct permissions should be like this:

```
$ ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown 
-r--r----- 1 root root 86 Jul 16 15:37 /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
```

Use `pkexec` like this to fix [ownership and permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions):

```
pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
```

Comment: i hope this will only apply to these 2 commands, and I won't be messing up with the rest of the system or any other command?

Comment: The two lines refer specifically to these two commands. If `user` is not in other ways given `sudo` rights no other commands can be sudoed by this user. Have a look at `man sudo` and `man sudoers`.

Comment: Initially I faced a chmod problem.. added a workout to this in the answer.. thanx @mgd

Comment: Thx! I think the information about what the proper ownership and permissions are was useful though--you may want to keep that in the answer as well. (You could even mention how to fix it with `pkexec` if it's been messed up, if you want.)

Comment: I'm on mac os x yosemite, sudo version 1.7.10p7 and I couldn't get any lines with `host = (root)` to work.  Here's the line that eventually worked for me to add permission for admin group to run the /usr/sbin/discoveryutil command without a password: `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/discoveryutil`

Comment: @StanKurdziel I tried with this line on Mac OS X Yosemite and it worked fine: `mgd ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/root/test`. I am user `mgd` and `ALL` means _"from all hosts"_. `/var/root/test` is a simple "Hello World" shell script with permissions: `-rwx------  1 root  wheel  27 12 Jun 09:54 /var/root/test`. I made _no_ other changes to the system.

Comment: This does not work.  user1 ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: "/Applications/MAMP\ PRO/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP\ PRO".  what could be wrong?

Comment: @BTRNaidu Several things could be wrong. One thing is that you quote the command string and _also_ escape the spaces. You should _either_ remove the quotes around the command _or_ remove the \ characters in the command (that escapes the spaces).

Comment: What is `host` in the sudoers file?

Comment: @user106563 the host field is used if you deploy sudoers files across multiple hosts. Then you can control which lines applies to which machines/hosts.

Comment: Have tried it for the last hours, without success. I'm working on Lubuntu 16.04, first of all edited `sudoers` with `leafpad`, but kept everything as it was by undoing everything when I realized it has to be `visudo` instead. Have added the line `nightcoder casa1  = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend` in every place, but the system keeps saying: `This utility may only be run by the root user.` when I run `pm-suspend` from the prompt.

Comment: @nightcod3r you still have to prefix your command with `sudo`. Otherwise, it does not run as root. I.e., `sudo pm-suspend`.

Comment: BEWARE: This sounded as - and perharps is - good advice. I removed the comment on /etc/sudoers so to enable the use of the /etc/sudoers.d... I created an empty file in /etc/sudoers.d and I'm now apparently locked out of sudo... I'll try to figure something out... (BTW, I'm on Windows10 Linux Subsystem [Ubuntu bash])

Comment: @arod did you take a look at the section "If sudoers is messed up" in my answer?

Comment: @mgd yes, I forgot to post it in the comment: pkexec gives me an error `$ pkexec visudo
prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM) failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: @arod check the last lines of my answer. Maybe the permissions of the new empty file is wrong and you can use pkexec to fix them.

Comment: For those that might have had my problem and luckily are using Windows10 Linux Subsystem, you can edit you files from Windows, going to the folder `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs`. There I could edit my `/etc/sudoers` file (In my case I put again the `#` on the line `includedir /etc/sudoers.d`). @mgd

Comment: WARNING regarding my last comment: since Windows does not manage permissions on files I'm thinking that when I saved sudoers and restarted my bash the sudoers file didn't have the correct permissions and so does not work... this should be fixed if you change the permissions of the file before restarting you bash subshell. In my case, I had to reinstall Bash Subsystem...

Comment: Can I request that the example be updated to include command field separators and examples of commands that have spaces in them?

Comment: @user447607 Sorry, but this answer is specifically about running a command using sudo without having to enter a password. It is _not_ covering every aspect of sudo. Please check the man page for sudo or ask a new question.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's almost full guide about NOPASSWD directive. Thank you.

Comment: Is there some way to restrict the command line options passed to the command? I see you have only specified shutdown, and not the arguments it takes.  I need to be able to switch to a non-privileged user in a script (using `sudo su -p <user>`) and obviously not being able to restrict the arguments taken would effectively eliminate the point of restricting it at all!

Comment: @Michael please read the man page. It is all written there. To quote it: However, you may also specify command line arguments (including wildcards). Alternately, you can specify "" to indicate that the command may only be run without command line arguments.

Comment: Try it and failed on centos, maybe try to enhance the help.

Comment: Put these at the END of the `sudoers` file, or else it might not work because `man sudo`.

Comment: What does `(root)` do here?

Comment: @lindhe it means the command can be run as `root`. See examples here
https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers in section *Runas_Spec*

Answer (score 27):

Sorry but there's so much confusion over this and some really complicated answers, that i feel i must weigh in here before someone misunderstands and does something crazy.

**Using visudo!!**

```
visudo
```

Add the following lines to the config:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot,/sbin/shutdown
```

This allows the commands, reboot and shutdown with any parameters to be executed from any user. The first "ALL" refers to the users, so it means ALL users. The second ALL refers to ALL hosts.

For a more verbose explanation see `man sudoers` as this provides further examples and these examples are several pages down but they are actually there if you dig deep enough.

Please stackexchange, just give simple, succinct answers.

Comment: There is *one* other answer.  Comparing this answer with the other:  the other answer explained how to set for one user on one host; the generalization to multiple users and multiple hosts is obvious.  Your answer gives a magic incantation (which actually applies to all users or all hosts, but that is entirely inobvious).  The other difference is that your answer gives two commands on a single line.  I didn't know you could do that - it's mildly useful, but given the complexity of sudoers I doubt I will ever use it.

Comment: You've got me. `visudo` only edits the sudoers file. Everything important and uncommented is in `ALL`.

Comment: @Owl Please provide the exact steps.

Answer (score 4):

The answer mentioning to set a *host* confused me, as I want to be able to have a *sudo* user be able to run privileged commands without requiring to consider such "host aspect"; any host should work, hence I use the special `ALL` reserved word.

Let's assume you want all *sudo* users (i.e., Unix users which are members of the Unix group *sudo*) to run the following commands as [*superuser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) (*root*) without having to enter their passwords:

- `sudo iftop`
- `sudo dbus-monitor --system`

First find out the executable's full path using `which`:

- `which iftop` > `/usr/sbin/iftop`
- `which dbus-monitor` > `/usr/bin/dbus-monitor`

Assuming the main *sudo* configuration file `etc/sudoers` contains the following directive (an Ubuntu default) ...

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

... then it is a best practice to add your configuration in its own separate file within the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/customizations`. This way, you will not run into problems when an update to the original *sudo* package wants to change the original `/etc/sudoers` file and the package manager notices conflicting edits done by you.

Run the following command to create and edit your own *sudo* customization file:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/customizations
```

<sup>Using the `visudo` command makes sure that there are no syntax erros in the file when saving it - syntax errors would otherwise make *sudo* fail to read all its configuration files, thereby breaking any subsequent `sudo` usage, effectively locking you out from any superuser usage, including fixing the syntax erros.</sup>

Now add the following lines to this file and save it:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iftop
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dbus-monitor --system
```

The `%sudo` at the beginning of these lines indicate they are rules for all members of group ("`%`") *sudo*.

Changes to *sudo* configuration files, including new files within the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, take effect immediately - no sudo "restart" required.

Now notice what happens when running the following commands: <sup>(for testing purposes, any current *sudo* ticket, i.e. the timespan without requiring to reenter the password, can be directly revoked/timed-out by executing `sudo -k`)</sup>

- `iftop`: fails with `You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)`. This is because running the configured commands without the `sudo` prefix behave unprivileged as usual.
- `sudo iftop`: this command will now run successfully without requiring a password.
- `sudo iftop -B` ("*display bandwidth in bytes*"): this command will also run successfully without requiring a password, because, as `man sudoers` explains, "*a simple file name [without parameters, in the configuration file] allows the user to run the command with any arguments they wish.*"
- `sudo dbus-monitor`: the system will ask for password, because, as `man sudoers` explains, "*if a [command, in the configuration file] has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in the [command] must match exactly those given by the user on the command line (or match the wildcards if there are any).*"
- `sudo dbus-monitor --system`: this command will now run successfully without requiring a password.
- `sudo dbus-monitor --system --foo`: the system will ask for password, as the arguments don't match the configuration.

Coming back to the initial question, for all users in the *sudo* group to be allowed to run the following commands without asking for their passwords ...

```
sudo reboot
sudo shutdown -r now
sudo shutdown -P now
```

... create a sudo configuration file with the following content (assuming Ubuntu standard locations for the executables `reboot` and `shutdown`):

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/reboot
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/shutdown -r now
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/shutdown -P now
```

Notice with this configuration, any *sudo* user can now also run `sudo reboot ...` **with any arguments, flags, and parameters** without having to provide a password, including e.g. `sudo reboot --poweroff --force`.
If this is not desired, but instead only `sudo reboot` **without any arguments/flags/parameters** shall be allowed, its configuration line has to be changed to ...

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/reboot ""
```

... because as `man sudoers` explains: "*you can specify "" to indicate that the command may only be run without command line arguments.*"