# How do I copy files that need root access with scp?

Tags: server, ssh, root, webserver

I have an Ubuntu server to which I am connecting using SSH.

I need to upload files from my machine into `/var/www/` on the server, the files in `/var/www/` are owned by `root`.

Using PuTTY, after I log in, I have to type `sudo su` and my password first in order to be able to modify files in `/var/www/`.

But when I am copying files using WinSCP , I can't create create/modify files in `/var/www/`, because the user I'm connecting with does not have permissions on files in `/var/www/` and I can't say `sudo su` as I do in case of an ssh session.

Do you know how i could deal with this ?

If I was working on my local machine, I would call `gksudo nautilus` but in this case I only have terminal access to the machine.

Comment: This seems more like a question for your virtual server provider, or for the putty or winscp developers.

Comment: @dobey you obviusly wrong , it is about ubuntu privileges !

Comment: Why is this closed? This is a perfectly valid question about copying files with scp - every web developer is familiar with this situation

Comment: [Copying protected files between servers in one line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/copying-protected-files-between-servers-in-one-line) should help.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I create a file (HTML in this case) on Windows computer and try to copy it with WinSCP to /var/www/html/website folder. And it says that there is a permission problem. Because I can copy to my /home folder I copied the file in two steps, but it isn't very convenient :-) I tried with adding my user to www-data group, but it didn't help. Any idea why adding to user to www-data still don't allow user to copy a file to folder which is owned by www-data group?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You're right, there is no `sudo` when working with `scp`. A workaround is to use `scp` to upload files to a directory where your user has permissions to create files, then log in via ssh and use `sudo` to move/copy files to their final destination.

```
scp -r folder/ user@server.tld:/some/folder/you/dont/need/sudo
ssh user@server.tld
 $ sudo mv /some/folder /some/folder/requiring/perms 
# YOU MAY NEED TO CHANGE THE OWNER like:
# sudo chown -R user:user folder
```

Another solution would be to change permissions/ownership of the directories you uploading the files to, so your non-privileged user is able to write to those directories.

Generally, working in the `root` account should be an exception, not a rule - the way you phrasing your question makes me think maybe you're abusing it a bit, which in turn leads to problems with permissions - under normal circumstances you don't need super-admin privileges to access your own files.

Technically, you can configure Ubuntu to allow remote login directly as `root`, but this feature is disabled for a reason, so I would strongly advice you against doing that.

Comment: i didn't get the first solution , could you please be a litle more spesific ?

Comment: Whe i say my own files i mean /var/www , i am using my vps as web server .... on my own folder i have full access

Comment: Re. the first solution. 1. `scp -R mysite dimitris@myserver.com:/home/dimitris/` 2. `ssh dimitris@myserver.com` 3. `sudo mv ~/mysite /var/www` - it's a 2-step process, first you `scp` the files to your home dir, then you log in via ssh and copy/move the files to where they should be

Comment: It's ludicrous you can't setup a `root` account to use `scp` for `root` owned files. `sudo` simply does not work. Who owns my computer me or Canonical? It's just as bad as Android and Google from that respect. IMHO. I just want to copy files from `/usr/local/bin` from one machine I OWN to another machine I OWN.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: indeed you can to set up your machines so you can SSH in as root, all it takes is a small change in a config. Once you do that you can scp files as root as much as you want.

Comment: "there is no sudo when working with scp", this is actually not completely true.  You can use sudo scp.. to gain access to local root files.  You can therefore ssh into the source machine, use and use sudo scp from there to get root files to or from a remote machine.

Comment: @Ellipticalview:That's a clever idea but it won't work in many scenarios (the source files are on a local machine behind NAT, no SSH server on the source machine, the files on the source machine are owned by root too :) )

Answer (score 138):

**Quick way**

From server to local machine:

```
ssh user@server "sudo cat /etc/dir/file" > /home/user/file
```

From local machine to server:

```
cat /home/user/file | ssh user@server "sudo tee -a /etc/dir/file"
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. It's simple, clean, reads or writes a root file with a single atomic operation, and requires nothing that's not already guaranteed to be there if you're using scp. Main drawback is that it does not copy permissions. If you want that, the tar solution is better.

This is a powerful technique, particularly if combined with xargs/bash magic to traverse paths..

Comment: I think the question was about uploading a file from local to remote and not vice versa

Comment: Beautifully done. This is exactly what I was looking for both up and down. Thank you

Comment: Deserves to be the top answer, for sure.

Comment: Can this be done for a directory instead of a file as well?

Comment: ...but you will need to pass `-t` to ssh, _unless {a number of prerequisite assumptions}_. Otherwise it will error with `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. And `tee -a`? The question is about copying, not about appending and at the same time echoing back to stdout.

Comment: I will add that another way around `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` is to specify `"sudo -S cat /etc/dir/file"` rather than just `"sudo cat /etc/dir/file"`

Comment: The `sudo -S cat ...` trick is great, but be aware, it WILL DISPLAY YOUR PASSWORD on the screen.

Comment: Another thing to have in mind is if the server has a display banner will be added to the file, as well as the message `Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed`. In order to avoid that happening you need to add `-o LogLevel=QUIET` to the ssh command. The command would be then `ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t user@server "sudo cat /etc/dir/file" > /home/user/file`.

Comment: any way to do this for entire folders?

Comment: how to do this for an entire directory: `ssh user@server "tar -cf - dir" | tar -x`

Comment: Thanks! Does the job perfectly. Be aware that the `tee` `-a` flag is for appending content . You need to get rid of it to overwrite content. And to be compliant with ShellCheck `SC2002` is more efficient to replace `cat` with redirection mechanism: `ssh user@server "sudo tee -a /etc/dir/file" < /home/user/file`.

Answer (score 47):

Another method is to copy using tar + ssh instead of scp:

```
tar -c -C ./my/local/dir \
  | ssh dimitris@myserver.com "sudo tar -x --no-same-owner -C /var/www"
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: I can't get this method to work successfully. As written I get `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. If I add "-t" to allocate a TTY then I get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`. I can't see this working without passwordless sudo.

Comment: @IBBoard : try the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10312700/10608) using ssh -t: `ssh -t dimitris@myserver.com "sudo tar -x --no-same-owner -C /var/www"`

Comment: @AlexanderBird While that works in many cases, I'm not sure it works here because we're trying to pipe a tarball over the SSH connection. See https://serverfault.com/questions/14389/when-would-ssh-t-not-be-appropriate-instead-of-ssh

Comment: This is what finally worked for me. You don't have permissions to a remote file that you want to copy to local, do a `sudo tar`, archive it, change permissions using `chmod` and `chown`, and then copy it to local. Especially if it's a directory.

Comment: tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
I think I'm selecting folders incorrectly is 'dir' the folder to be compressed? Is '/var/www/dir' the folder that will be created by uncompressing?

Comment: If you're already in the directory you want to tar up, use `tar -c * | ssh dimitris@myserver.com "sudo tar -x --no-same-owner -C /var/www"`

Comment: Building on the above, what I tend to do is: tar -cf - * | ssh user@myserver.com sudo /bin/bash -c '( cd /var/www && tar -xf - --no-same-owner )', this is typically because /bin/bash is listed in sudoers but tar might not be at $CORP, or sometimes it is su - that is listed. It can get uglier :)

Answer (score 35):

You can also use `ansible` to accomplish this.

### Copy to remote host using [ansible's `copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html):

```
ansible -i HOST, -b -m copy -a "src=SRC_FILEPATH dest=DEST_FILEPATH" all
```

### Fetch from remote host using [ansible's `fetch` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html):

```
ansible -i HOST, -b -m fetch -a "src=SRC_FILEPATH dest=DEST_FILEPATH flat=yes" all
```

NOTE:

- The comma in the `-i HOST,` syntax is not a typo.  It is the way to use ansible without needing an inventory file.
- `-b` causes the actions on the server to be done as root. `-b` expands to `--become`, and the default `--become-user` is root, with the default `--become-method` being sudo.
- `flat=yes` copies *just* the file, doesn't copy whole remote path leading to the file
- Using wildcards in the file paths isn't supported by these ansible modules.
- Copying a directory *is* supported by the `copy` module, but *not* by the `fetch` module.

### Specific Invocation for this Question

Here's an example that is specific and fully specified, assuming the directory on your local host containing the files to be distributed is `sourcedir`, and that the remote target's hostname is `hostname`:

```
cd sourcedir && \
ansible \
   --inventory-file hostname, \ 
   --become \
   --become-method sudo \
   --become-user root \
   --module-name copy \
   --args "src=. dest=/var/www/" \
   all
```

With the concise invocation being:

```
cd sourcedir && \
ansible -i hostname, -b -m copy -a "src=. dest=/var/www/" all
```

P.S., I realize that saying "just install this fabulous tool" is kind of a
tone-deaf answer. But I've found ansible to be *super* useful for administering remote servers, so installing it will surely bring you other benefits beyond deploying files.

Comment: I like the this answer but I recommend you direct it at the asked question versus more generalized commentary before upvote. something like `ansible -i "hostname," all -u user --become -m copy -a ...`

Comment: @MikeD: how do the above changes look?

Comment: better but it's fails, `--module-name` is the correct switch name. and since `hostname` is the only host in your inventory, you can just say `all`

Comment: ah, definitely a great point with `all`, I've updated all 3 cmds with that. And good catch with `--module-name` instead of `--module`.

Comment: Would something like `-i 'host,'` be valid syntax?  I think it's easy to lose punctuation like that when reading a command.  (For the reader I mean, if not the shell.)

Comment: hi @mwfearnley: I'm not sure I follow the question.  The syntax is valid, in that it is the only way supported by ansible to directly specify the hostnames without using an inventory file.  I agree that it's not obvious nor intuitive, but "it is what it is". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm just wondering if the `host,` could be validly wrapped in quotes, just to show someone reading a script that: a) yes,  there's supposed to be a comma there; and: b) don't worry, the extra punctuation won't, and can't, get misinterpreted by the shell.

Comment: @mwfearnley: sure, the shell will treat `-i 'host,'` and same as `-i host,` or `-i "host,"`.  In general I prefer to keep these invocations as short as possible to keep them from being daunting, but you should feel free to make it as verbose and explicit as you think is needed for clarity.

Comment: Way to go thinking outside the box! Great use of Ansible

Comment: If you got something like `"msg": "Missing sudo password"` you can specify sudo user by appending `--extra-vars "ansible_become_pass=yourPasswor"` after `-b`

Comment: @Mohamed : interesting workaround. My instinctual reaction is that you should be careful specifying your password in clear text like this. i.e., Ensure it's not getting written to your shell history & that you are not running on a shared server, since the parameter would be visible in the process table.  Also make sure ansible isn't logging / storing this anywhere locally or on the remote server.

Comment: This should be the best answer. I just added `-K` which asks for sudo password.

Answer (score 25):

May be the best way is to use `rsync` (*Cygwin*/*cwRsync* in Windows) over SSH?

For example, to upload files with owner `www-data`:

```
rsync -a --rsync-path="sudo -u www-data rsync" path_to_local_data/ login@srv01.example.com:/var/www
```

In your case, if you need root privileges, command will be like this:

```
rsync -a --rsync-path="sudo rsync" path_to_local_data/ login@srv01.example.com:/var/www
```

See: [scp to remote server with sudo](https://superuser.com/a/702620).

Comment: Thanks! This is the best way for copying big protected files!

Answer (score 12):

When you run `sudo su`, any files you create will be owned by root, but it is not possible by default to directly log in as root with ssh or scp.  It is also not possible to use sudo with scp, so the files are not usable.  Fix this by claiming ownership over your files:

Assuming your user name was dimitri, you could use this command.

```
sudo chown -R dimitri:dimitri /home/dimitri
```

From then on, as mentioned in other answers, the "Ubuntu" way is to use sudo, and not root logins.  It is a useful paradigm, with great security advantages.

Comment: i am using this solution any way , but what if i could get full access to my own file system , i don't want to type `sudo chow ...` for every single directory :S

Comment: Changing ownership of all system files to the user for passing convenience is highly discouraged.  It allows any userspace bug you might encounter to severely compromise the security of your system.  It is much better to change the ownership of the files that you need to change or update by SCP, but to leave everything else owned by root (like it is supposed to be).  That said, the `-R` in `chown` tells it to change the ownership of that directory, and all children files and directories recursively... so you can do anything you like.

Comment: hmm .... that seems working fine , thank you !

sorry i can't upvote (system does not allow me to do ...)

Answer (score 7):

If you use the OpenSSH tools instead of PuTTY, you can accomplish this by initiating the `scp` file transfer on the server with `sudo`. Make sure you have an `sshd` daemon running on your local machine. With `ssh -R` you can give the server a way to contact your machine.

On your machine:

```
ssh -R 11111:localhost:22 REMOTE_USERNAME@SERVERNAME
```

In addition to logging you in on the server, this will forward every connection made on the server's port 11111 to your machine's port 22: the port your `sshd` is listening on.

On the server, start the file transfer like this:

```
cd /var/www/
sudo scp -P 11111 -r LOCAL_USERNAME@localhost:FOLDERNAME .
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a modified version of Willie Wheeler's answer that transfers the file(s) via tar but also supports passing a password to sudo on the remote host.

```
(stty -echo; read passwd; stty echo; echo $passwd; tar -cz foo.*) \
  | ssh remote_host "sudo -S bash -c \"tar -C /var/www/ -xz; echo\""
```

The little bit of extra magic here is the -S option to sudo. From the sudo man page:

> -S, --stdin
>                    Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.

Now we actually want the output of tar to be piped into ssh and that redirects the stdin of ssh to the stdout of tar, removing any way to pass the password into sudo from the interactive terminal. (We could use sudo's ASKPASS feature on the remote end but that is another story.) We can get the password into sudo though by capturing it in advance and prepending it to the tar output by performing those operations in a subshell and piping the output of the subshell into ssh. This also has the added advantage of not leaving an environment variable containing our password dangling in our interactive shell.

You'll notice I didn't execute 'read' with the -p option to print a prompt. This is because the password prompt from sudo is conveniently passed back to the stderr of our interactive shell via ssh. You might wonder "how is sudo executing given it is running inside ssh to the right of our pipe?" When we execute multiple commands and pipe the output of one into another, the parent shell (the interactive shell in this case) executes each command in the sequence immediately after executing the previous. As each command behind a pipe is executed the parent shell attaches (redirects) the stdout of the left-hand side to the stdin of the right-hand side. Output then becomes input as it passes through processes. We can see this in action by executing the entire command and backgrounding the process group (Ctrl-z) before typing our password, and then viewing the process tree.

```
$ (stty -echo; read passwd; stty echo; echo $passwd; tar -cz foo.*) | ssh 
remote_host "sudo -S bash -c \"tar -C /var/www/ -xz; echo\""
[sudo] password for bruce: 
[1]+  Stopped                 ( stty -echo; read passwd; stty echo; echo 
$passwd; tar -cz foo.* ) | ssh remote_host "sudo -S bash -c \"tar -C 
/var/www/ -xz; echo\""

$ pstree -lap $$
bash,7168
  ├─bash,7969
  ├─pstree,7972 -lap 7168
  └─ssh,7970 remote_host sudo -S bash -c "tar -C /var/www/ -xz; echo"`
```

Our interactive shell is PID 7168, our subshell is PID 7969 and our ssh process is PID 7970.

The only drawback is that read will accept input before sudo has time to send back it's prompt. On a fast connection and fast remote host you won't notice this but you might if either is slow. Any delay will not affect the ability to enter the prompt; it just might appear after you have started typing.

Note I simply added a host file entry for "remote_Host" to my local machine for the demo.

Comment: If using bash, you can use `read -s passwd` instead of using `stty -echo` and `stty echo`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use script I've written being inspired by this topic:

```
touch /tmp/justtest && scpassudo /tmp/justtest remoteuser@ssh.superserver.com:/tmp/
```

but this requires some crazy stuff (which is btw. automatically done by script)

1. server which file is being sent to will no longer ask for password while establishing ssh connection to source computer
2. due to necessarility of lack of sudo prompt on the server, sudo will no longer ask for password on remote machine, for user

Here goes the script:

```
interface=wlan0
if [[ $# -ge 3 ]]; then interface=$3; fi
thisIP=$(ifconfig | grep $interface -b1 | tail -n1 | egrep -o '[0-9.]{4,}' -m1 | head -n 1)
thisUser=$(whoami)
localFilePath=/tmp/justfortest
destIP=192.168.0.2
destUser=silesia
#dest 
#destFolderOnRemoteMachine=/opt/glassfish/glassfish/
#destFolderOnRemoteMachine=/tmp/

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then 
echo -e "Send file to remote server to locatoin where root permision is needed.\n\tusage: $0 local_filename [username@](ip|host):(remote_folder/|remote_filename) [optionalInterface=wlan0]"
echo -e "Example: \n\ttouch /tmp/justtest &&\n\t $0 /tmp/justtest remoteuser@ssh.superserver.com:/tmp/ "
exit 1
fi

localFilePath=$1

test -e $localFilePath 

destString=$2
usernameAndHost=$(echo $destString | cut -f1 -d':')

if [[ "$usernameAndHost" == *"@"* ]]; then
destUser=$(echo $usernameAndHost | cut -f1 -d'@')
destIP=$(echo $usernameAndHost | cut -f2 -d'@')
else
destIP=$usernameAndHost
destUser=$thisUser
fi

destFolderOnRemoteMachine=$(echo $destString | cut -f2 -d':')

set -e #stop script if there is even single error

echo 'First step: we need to be able to execute scp without any user interaction'
echo 'generating public key on machine, which will receive file'
ssh $destUser@$destIP 'test -e ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -a -e ~/.ssh/id_rsa || ssh-keygen -t rsa'
echo 'Done'

echo 'Second step: download public key from remote machine to this machine so this machine allows remote machine (this one receiveing file) to login without asking for password'

key=$(ssh $destUser@$destIP 'cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
if ! grep "$key" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; then
echo $key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo 'Added key to authorized hosts'
else
echo "Key already exists in authorized keys"
fi

echo "We will want to execute sudo command remotely, which means turning off asking for password"
echo 'This can be done by this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/a/10310407/781312'
echo 'This you have to do manually: '
echo -e "execute in new terminal: \n\tssh $destUser:$destIP\nPress enter when ready"
read 
echo 'run there sudo visudo'
read
echo 'change '
echo '    %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL'
echo 'to'
echo '    %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
echo "After this step you will be done."
read

listOfFiles=$(ssh $destUser@$destIP "sudo ls -a")

if [[ "$listOfFiles" != "" ]]; then 
echo "Sending by executing command, in fact, receiving, file on remote machine"
echo 'Note that this command (due to " instead of '', see man bash | less -p''quotes'') is filled with values from local machine'
echo -e "Executing \n\t""identy=~/.ssh/id_rsa; sudo scp -i \$identy $(whoami)@$thisIP:$(readlink -f $localFilePath) $destFolderOnRemoteMachine"" \non remote machine"
ssh $destUser@$destIP "identy=~/.ssh/id_rsa; sudo scp -i \$identy $(whoami)@$thisIP:$(readlink -f $localFilePath) $destFolderOnRemoteMachine"
ssh $destUser@$destIP "ls ${destFolderOnRemoteMachine%\\\\n}/$(basename $localFilePath)"
if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then echo "errror in validating"; else echo -e "SUCCESS! Successfully sent\n\t$localFilePath \nto \n\t$destString\nFind more at http://arzoxadi.tk"; fi
else
echo "something went wrong with executing sudo on remote host, failure"

fi
ENDOFSCRIPT
) | sudo tee /usr/bin/scpassudo && chmod +x /usr/bin/scpassudo
```

Comment: @Braiam yeah, sure, sorry for link, the script is pretty long and that was the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine ssh, sudo and e.g tar to transfer files between servers without being able to log in as root and not having the permission to access the files with your user. This is slightly fiddly, so I've written a script to help this. You can find the script here: https://github.com/sigmunau/sudoscp

or here:

```
#! /bin/bash
res=0
from=$1
to=$2
shift
shift
files="$@"
if test -z "$from" -o -z "$to" -o -z "$files"
then
    echo "Usage: $0    (file)*"
    echo "example: $0 server1 server2 /usr/bin/myapp"
    exit 1
fi

read -s -p "Enter Password: " sudopassword
echo ""
temp1=$(mktemp)
temp2=$(mktemp)
(echo "$sudopassword";echo "$sudopassword"|ssh $from sudo -S tar c -P -C / $files 2>$temp1)|ssh $to sudo -S tar x -v -P -C / 2>$temp2
sourceres=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if [ $? -ne 0 -o $sourceres -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failure!" >&2
    echo "$from output:" >&2
    cat $temp1 >&2
    echo "" >&2
    echo "$to output:" >&2
    cat $temp2 >&2
    res=1
fi

rm $temp1 $temp2
exit $res
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you please include the script in your answer? I know it is unlikely but if the github repo was ever removed or the url changed then the answer would be void. It is better to include the script directly and leave the github repo as a source.

Answer (score 1):

The scp command can't do what you are asking.

The approach I take is to use `sudo` on the local or remote system (when it's needed to read or writ a file).

### Copy remote root access only file to local root access only file

For example, let's say there is a privileged file `/etc/pki/private/identity.pem` on a remote system and you want to copy it to your local system.  The file requires root/sudo access to read or write the file.

To do that, I use this command pattern:

```
ROOT_ONLY_FILE=/etc/pki/private/identity.pem
ssh host sudo ls -l $ROOT_ONLY_FILE
ssh host sudo cat $ROOT_ONLY_FILE | sudo tee $ROOT_ONLY_FILE > /dev/null
sudo chmod 600 $ROOT_ONLY_FILE
# sudo chown root:grp $ROOT_ONLY_FILE
```

It's very important to keep the owner, group and read-write modes set properly when copying these privileged files.  That is why I start with the `ls -l` of the remote file.

The chmod and chown commands are intended to make sure the copy of the file has the same permissions as the original file.

### Copy remote root access only file to local file

```
ssh host sudo cat /var/log/messages | cat > /tmp/host.messages
```

Using `sudo cat $file` lets you read the file.  You can't use `scp` because scp would not allow access to that privileged file but `sudo cat` runs on the remote system as root so it works.

### Copy local file to remote file that requires special access only

There are times when you want to update a remote file that is owned by tomcat or another user.  In this case, you can still use sudo because root is allowed to write to the remote file and doesn't change the files ownership or permission bits when it writes a file that already exists.

The command is:

```
cat logging.properties | ssh sudo tee /home/tomcat/conf/logging.properties > /dev/null
```

### Copying directories using tar

While the question only asked about files it's important to realize that this approach can also work with directories.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10028/119816 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

An older question, I know, but times change and so do some techniques.  Just in case someone is still looking for a streamlined way to accomplish this.

### Assumptions

1. Your user on the server is a sudoers.
2. You are running Windows 10.
3. The files in `/var/www` should belong to user:group `www-data:www-data`

### Concept

The concept is to combine remote commands over `ssh` and `scp` file transfersers without relying on GUIs such as `PuTTy` or `WinSCP`.  These commands can be run either from a `Command Prompt` or `PowerShell`.  There are five main tasks to permorm:

1. Environment setup
2. Transfer files to server
3. Set remote file permissions
4. Transfer between remote folders
5. Cleanup

Tasks 3-5 can be performed in a single step.  If you plan to do this often, leaving the environment setup will allow you to omit tasks 1 and 5.

### Environment Setup

You may or may not already have folder you can use as a temporary repository for the transfer.  If not, you can run:

```
ssh user@server.tld "mkdir ~/wwwtemp"
```

Depending on your server's settings, you may or may not be prompted for `user`'s password/passphrase to authenticate the `ssh` session.

Once the session is authenticated, the `mkdir ~/wwwtemp` command will execute then the `ssh` session will terminate, and you will be back at your prompt (`Command Prompt` or `PowerShell`).

### Transfer Files to Server

The next thing to do is to transfer the files from the local Windows machine to the Ubuntu server using `scp` like so:

```
scp -R local\path user@server.tld:~/wwwtemp/
```

Depending on your server's authentication method, you may or not need to enter a password/passphrase.

### Permissions and Final Destination of Files

Once the file transfer has completed, you can run a series of commands over `ssh` like thusly:

```
ssh -t user@server.tld "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/wwwtemp  && sudo mv -R ~/wwwtemp/* /var/www/ && sudo rmdir ~/wwwtemp"
```

Again, depending on the authentication method of your server you may or may not be prompted for a `password/passphrase`.  Regardless of your authentication method, `sudo` will prompt you for `user`'s password.  Unless, of course you have disable requirement for password when `user` runs `chown` `mv` and `rmdir`. See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) for guidance on how to do that.

This step covers tasks 3-5:

3. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/wwwtemp` recursively sets the desired file permissions on the files you just uploaded.
4. `sudo mv -R ~/wwwtemp/* /var/www/` recursively moves the contents of the temporary repository to its final destination.
5. `sudo rmdir ~/wwwtemp` removes the temporary repository.  It is necessary to use `sudo` here since we changed the directory owner in task 3.

Of course, `&&` separates each command.  The commands will be performed in sequence.  If you plan to keep the repository `wwwtemp`, you can omit the final command in the sequence.

### Notes

You can omit `&& sudo rmdir ~/wwwtemp` from the end of the final `ssh` command string if you would like to continue using the temporary repository in future.  Doing so also means that you can omit the first `ssh` command each time you desire to transfer files to your server in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the remote machine, create a folder inside the desired folder, like this:

   ```
   cd /var/www
   sudo mkdir my_folder
   ```
2. Change the ownership of `my_folder` to your own user:

   ```
   sudo chown -R replace_with_your_user:replace_with_a_user_group my_folder/
   ```

   This will recursively change the ownership inside `my_folder`.
3. From your local machine, transfer the file you want to the new created folder:

   ```
   scp /path/to/your/file replace_with_your_user@replace_with_the_remote_machine_ip:/var/www/my_folder
   ```
4. When the transfer is done, you may want to move your file to the desired location in the remote machine and delete the created folder. In this case:

   ```
   sudo mv my_folder/replace_with_your_file /var/www
   sudo rm -Rf my_folder/
   ```

Comment: My answer will protect your machine from security issues, like setting the permission of /var/www to 777. Don´t do this.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ scp -i example.pem -r sourcefilr.txt ubuntu@10.12.3.4:/example_folder
```

Before executing this command we need to give full permissions to example_folder:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 example_folder
```