# Unable to use :NOPASSWD in sudoers

Tags: sudo

I have the following sudoers file:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for misha: 
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

misha   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/pm-suspend

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I want to run /sbin/pm-suspend without entering my password.  I'm following this example: [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/specific-sudo-commands-without-password)

However, when I try to suspend, I still get the password prompt:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~$ sudo /sbin/pm-suspend
[sudo] password for misha:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pm-suspend` is not under `/sbin/`

```
misha   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

Might give you better luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally if you are customizing what commands can be run via `sudo` you should be making these changes in a separate file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of editing the `sudoers` file directly. You should also always use `visudo` to edit the file(s). You should NEVER grant `NOPASSWD` on `ALL` commands.

Example:
`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/sleepytime`

Insert your line granting permission:
`misha ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend`

Then save and exit and `visudo` will warn you if you have any syntax errors.

You can run `sudo -l` to see the permissions that your user has been granted, if any of the user specific `NOPASSWD` commands appear BEFORE any `%groupyouarein ALL=(ALL) ALL` command in the output you will be prompted for your password.

If you find yourself creating lots of these sudoers.d files then perhaps you will want to create them named per user so they are easier to visualize. Keep in mind that the ordering of the FILE NAMES and of the RULES within the file is very important, the LAST one loaded wins, whether it is MORE or LESS permissive than the previous entries.

> You can control the file name ordering by using a prefix of 00-99 or aa/bb/cc, though also keep in mind that if you have ANY files that don't have numeric prefix, they will load after the numbered files, overriding the settings. This is because depending on your language settings the "lexical sorting" the shell uses sorts numbers first and then may interleave upper and lowercase when sorting in "ascending" order.

Try running `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | sort` and `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | LANG=C sort` to see whether your current language prints `AaBbCc` etc or `ABC` then `abc` to determine what the best "last" letter prefix to use would be.