# How to run a command with one click, preferably from unity's launcher

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher, openvpn

I'd like to run this command without having to open up terminal every time.

`sudo openvpn --config /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/vpnbook-euro2-udp25000.ovpn --auth-user-pass /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/password.txt`

Would it be possible to make a script launchable from Unity's launcher?

Answer (score 3):

First, because you're about not to use terminal, I change `sudo` to `gksu`. And then, if you've created a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gksu openvpn --config /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/vpnbook-euro2-udp25000.ovpn --auth-user-pass /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/password.txt
```

and named it `your-script.sh`, you can create a file like this (taken from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop#answer-64237)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=</Path/to/your-script.sh>
Name=<Enter visible name here>
Comment=<Enter comment here>
Icon=</Path/to/icon/you/like>
```

For example, you named the file `your-launcher.desktop`. Place it in `~/.local/share/applications/`, open nautilus and drag-and-drop `your-launcher.desktop` into the Unity launcher.

Besides that, maybe (but I've not tested yet) you can place `gksu openvpn --config /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/vpnbook-euro2-udp25000.ovpn --auth-user-pass /home/ubuntu/Documents/vpnbook/password.txt` directly in `Exec` field of `your-launcher.desktop`.

Comment: In addition, if you don't want to provide your password every time you run the command, do the following: 1) Do not change sudo to gksu 2) Make openvpn sudoable without password. Here's how: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: also, don't forget to make it executable