# How to make a command execuitable without root previlages?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I want to make some commands,such as ntpdate,shutdown etc, to execute without asking me for a password or without using "sudo" for **"all users"**(even normal users who have no sudo privileges) . I want only a few commends to behave in such way and not every command.

Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: Please explain a bit **why** you want that - the stability of linux comes a good deal from strict restrictions on what a "normal" user can do.

Comment: Just refer this link. This may help you i think.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: @VelmuruganS ya thanks that link is helpful but m lookin for multiple users

Comment: @guntbert m fed up of typing my password for every small and frequently used commands and also i want to give pivilage of some commands to other users without giving them the password