# Editing Sudoers to avoid typing a password for iwconfig command

Tags: password, sudo

I wanted to follow this guide to avoid typing a password every time I want to use "sudo iwconfig" command

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821

I tried the steps with "apt-get" command and it worked

```
sudo select-editor
sudo visudo
add %admin ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get to the bottom line
```

but they didn't work with "iwconfig"

I believe the reason behind that is "iwconfig" source files are not stored in "/usr/bin/" directory because `ls /usr/bin/ | less` doesn't show anything named iwconfig

So, what is the directory I should enter before iwconfig?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem using the following

```
sudo visudo
```

adding `%admin ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/sbin/iwconfig` to the bottom line

Comment: be careful with `%admin` since everyone in the admin group can do this.

Answer (score 3):

### Running iwconfig without password

Create a file called iwconfig in /etc/sudoers.d/:

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
```

Add the following:

```
your-user-name ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwconfig
```

Check if the file has the right permissions:

```
$ ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
```

Should be:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 0 Feb 1 21:34 /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
```

If not:

```
$ pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
$ pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
```

If you cannot open the iwconfig file, try:

```
pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/iwconfig
```

-- Regards

@see:

- [permissions - How to suid iwconfig on Debian wheezy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67671/how-to-suid-iwconfig-on-debian-wheezy)
- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Comment: Created the file, checked the permissions and they were fine but iwconfig still asks for the password

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -u root iwconfig`? This should not bring up a password prompt. Additionally `sudo -l` should display: `(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwconfig`

Comment: To shorten it type `nano ~/.bashrc` and add `alias iwconfig="sudo iwconfig"` at the end of the file.

Comment: Missed `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I actually could get it to work using the other answer but thank you for the replies :)