# How do I make a sudo command start at start-up with a 1 minute delay?

Tags: boot, sudo, command-line

I would like to make a `sudo` command (`sudo service smbd restart`) run after 1 minute of being logged on. How would I go about doing this?

P.S. This is a system with no monitor, mouse, keyboard or speakers connected - it's a printer and file server.

Comment: What do you mean by logged on? 1 minute after start computer or 1 minute after a user have logged in?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: What Fischer said, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964254/bash-script-to-run-in-5-minutes

Comment: If some answer satisfy the OP, please mark it as answered. See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8333/unanswered-questions-what-to-do

Answer (score 10):

A) If it's at *system* start-up, add this to the end of your `/etc/rc.local` (1):  (before the `exit 0`, obviously):

```
( sleep 60 && service smbd restart )&
```

Note:

1. the outer  `()` are needed so that the complex command detach itself and go to the background, allowing the boot process to finish;
2. `sudo` is not needed there,  `/etc/rc.local` is executed by `root`;
3. Are you really sure this is a solution? It is a race condition asking to happen...

B) if it's at *user login*, you need two steps:

1. configure your `sudo` so that it will not ask for a password for `service smbd restart` command (see [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password));
2. prepare a script with the following contents and add it to your autorun/startup program (varies with the desktop environment you are using).

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
( sleep 60 && service smbd restart )&
```

*Footnotes*

(1) check if `/etc/rc.local` is executable. Otherwise, make it so with `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 4):

Try `man sleep`:

```
sleep 60 && sudo service smbd restart
```

Put this in the autorun programs or scripts executed at login time.

Comment: If you do not configure appropriately the `sudoers` file, it will not work (will stop asking for a password). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: Agreed. Your answer is certainly more complete than mine. Here I was simply trying to point the user towards a solution.