# Run 'sudo service mongod start' at boot time

Tags: boot, mongodb

Ubuntu 15.10

I am TOTALLY confused by all the posts about the new service loaders, and rather concerned that Mongo don't seem to think that it is their issue to solve. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690993/mongodb-3-0-2-wont-start-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15-10) is one of several posts that suggest it is nearly impossible, except with manual interventions. (A solution from 2011 is not a solution given the current mix of technology used by Ubuntu and Mongo.)

And yet, what I know is that `mongod` no longer starts at boot time, but that if I open a console and run `sudo service mongod start`, then it works.

What is the simplest way to automate this during the initial bootup?

Comment: See this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/419169/how-do-i-make-a-sudo-command-start-at-start-up-with-a-1-minute-delay

Comment: Pointing the questioner at _even more_ woefully outdated and non-Ubuntu-init-system information (for Ubuntu 11 and for `rc.local` of all things!) really doesn't help matters when the the questioner identifies this as part of the very problem, Parto.  See http://askubuntu.com/a/617869/43344, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187540/5132 for some of the many discussions of starting MongoDB **with systemd and upstart**.  My experience, for what it's worth, is that "nearly impossible" should read "fairly easy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `update-rc.d`. Enter following command to add mongod to system services means starting at boot time:

```
sudo update-rc.d mongod defaults
```

Comment: and to remove it ?

Comment: `sudo update-rc.d mongod remove`

Comment: `update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/mongod`

Comment: @chovy: which Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: I have Ubuntu server 64 - 16.04. When I installed mongo for ubuntu (as described in official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) there was no init script created.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
sudo update-rc.d mongodb defaults
```