# bypass sudo for a group of commands

Tags: sudo, users, privileges, execute-command

I need to bypass `sudo` for a group of commands for a certain user so the command is just executed without using the `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to allow a user to reboot without using the sudo cammand, add the command to  `/etc/sudoers` file : add this line to the file :

```
your-username ALL=NOPASSWD: reboot
```

A more detailed description can be found here: [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to bypass sudo, I assume you do not want to type sudo each time you execute certain commands. `su` will change the user session to root, making all further commands executed as root, hence no need for `sudo`.

try:

`sudo su`

```
paul@test-machine:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for paul: 
root@test-machine:/home/paul# 
root@test-machine:/home/paul# exit
exit
paul@test-machine:~$
```

This command executes the change of session as root (`sudo`), to the root user (`su root`). su assumes you want to be root, so you don't need to tell it the user.

Information found here: http://www.linfo.org/su.html

> su is usually the simplest and most convenient way to change the
>   ownership of a login session to root or to any other user.
>
> Syntax
>
> A simplified expression of the syntax of the su command is:
>
> ```
> su [options] [commands] [-] [username]
> ```
>
> The square brackets indicate that the enclosed item is optional. Thus,
>   the simplest way to use the su command is to just type:
>
> ```
> su
> ```
>
> The operating system assumes that, in the absence of a username, the
>   user wants to change to a root session, and thus the user is prompted
>   for the root password as soon as the ENTER key is pressed. This
>   produces the same result as typing:
>
> ```
> su root
> ```
>
> If the correct password is provided, ownership of the session is
>   changed to root.

Comment: this will enable the user to do any thing he needs , i just want to do this for a group of commands

Comment: Can you explain your use in a little more detail.

Comment: i need to enable the reboot command for a user so he writes reboot without sudo

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but it came up first in my google search of "command to bypass sudo"  You should really use visudo instead of editing /etc/sudoers directly.  visudo checks to make sure you didn't enter anything wrong in the sudoers file...which could potentially break something.

See, e.g., [Why I must use 'visudo' to edit the '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625821/why-i-must-use-visudo-to-edit-the-etc-sudoers-file)

Not sure what was wrong with this post, please clarify.