# Why I must use 'visudo' to edit the '/etc/sudoers' file?

Tags: sudo, visudo

In `/etc/sudoers`, it says:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
```

My question is, why must this file be edited with `visudo`?

It seems I was able to edit the file successfully with `gedit`, by issuing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

If I was able to edit it with `gedit`, why must I use `visudo`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is just safer to use [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/visudo.8.html). You can edit [`/etc/sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) directly, but if you make a typo there, you will not be able to use [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html) anymore. And won't be able to fix your error.

`visudo` locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits, provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.

You can read more by:

```
man visudo
```

Comment: Thanks! An off-topic question if you don't mind: what is the difference between `#` and `%` in the sudoers file? Are they both there to indicate the line is a comment?

Comment: Only # is a comment. % is for group. And if you do not know file format, you definitely should not directly edit sudoers.

Comment: Thanks again. I have to do it following the instructions here http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `visudo`, if you manage to introduce a syntax error, `visudo` just exits with a prompt saying "What now?", but it doesn't give you any options on-screen.

However, the options are stated in the [`visudo` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/visudo.8.html):

> ```
> visudo parses the sudoers file after the edit and will not save the
> changes if there is a syntax error. Upon finding an error, visudo will
> print a message stating the line number(s) where the error occurred
> and the user will receive the "What now?" prompt. At this point the
> user may enter 'e' to re-edit the sudoers file, 'x' to exit without
> saving the changes, or 'Q' to quit and save changes. The 'Q' option
> should be used with extreme care because if visudo believes there to
> be a parse error, so will sudo and no one will be able to sudo again
> until the error is fixed. If 'e' is typed to edit the sudoers file
> after a parse error has been detected, the cursor will be placed on
> the line where the error occurred (if the editor supports this
> feature).
> ```

However, this is pretty much a wall of text, and not very intuitive.

To avoid confusion if you get a syntax error, I'll recommend that you define the following function in your `~/.bashrc` (or another file sourced from `~/.bashrc`).

```
# Improved visudo command
editsudo () {
  echo "Valid options at the 'What now?' prompt:"
  echo "  e : Re-edit the sudoers file"
  echo "  x : Exit without saving the changes"
  echo "  Q : Quit and save changes (NOT recommended)"
  sudo visudo
}
```

Now this has 2 advantages:

1. The command `editsudo` ensures to run `sudo visudo` (so it's shorter).
2. The command `editsudo` prints a help text first, so that if you exits out with an error you have the relevant info right above.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the horse's mouth, `man visudo`:

> `visudo` edits the **sudoers** file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).  `visudo` locks the **sudoers** file against multiple simultaneous edits, provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors before installing the edited file.  If the **sudoers** file is currently being edited you will receive a message to try again later.
>
> `visudo` parses the **sudoers** file after editing and will not save the changes if there is a syntax error.  Upon finding an error, `visudo` will print a message stating the line number(s) where the error occurred and the user will receive the “What now?” prompt.  [...]