# Change manual page option color

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, manpage

I see the man page options very dark. I use the konsole terminal in Kubuntu. I want to change the colour, how can I do it.

[The solution that I've found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages) only works until shutdown. The terminal responds to the first command with: "No such file or directory"
 [image]

Comment: brutal tip: If you want a bash command be done every startup, is enough to write it in `/etc/rc.local` cheer

Comment: @gio900 it doesn't work for me. Can you tell me where do I have to copy it exactly inside that file?

Comment: that file work as root, so use it with ~ instead of the absolute path isn't the best idea. But... wait! Why don't import just a different colors schema to the Konsole? https://github.com/nareshv/kde-konsole-colorschemes

Comment: I wrote the command with absolute path I think: sudo vi /etc/rc.local then just above the last line (exit 0) I copied all that code. Could you make an answer and explain how to import a color schema of those? And what do represent all that numbers in the terminal pictures. Another question: if I write sudo -s in rc.local y will be root every time I open the terminal? Thank you.

Comment: I was able to change the color of the options by changing all the colors editing the profile. But I don't know what represents each color (I do know what are foreground and background but I don't know what represents the 1-8 colors)

Comment: nether me know the colors options meaning, you shall try or ask someone else. To let an user do root command without use psw, look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password NB 1 is **not a good idea do every command in bash as root**, 2 the ~ is a relative path: means /home/youruserdirectory, so if you write ~ in the `/etc/rc.local` file,so as root, that relative path means /root.Also, if you create a file/directory as root you have to ask yourself if is better change the howner of it by `chown`. Use `man chown` to see how it work.Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of your man page by adding following line in your `.bashrc` file.

```
man() {
    env LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;32m' \
    man "$@"
}
```

Here `LESS_TERMCAP_md` is for man bold letter. (`man` by default uses `less` to display page.)

Replace the color code `\e[1;32m` with desired one. you can find these color code [here](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

[image]

Comment: I opened the `.bashrc` file with Kate. I wrote that at the end of the file and saved it. Then I wrote `man sudo` in the terminal, and didn't notice any change.

Comment: Try to change color from the terminal profile. In gnome-terminal, right click in terminal, select profile -> profile preferences -> color

Comment: Oh I think there is a confusion. I'm using the konsole terminal in kubuntu. Should have written it down. I found the solution here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages