# Allow to mount/unmount a specific device to a specific user

Tags: mount

I know I can give permission to use "mount/unmount" through sudo some users without password.

But how can I give permission to use "mount/unmount" only for /dev/sda2 and not for /dev/sda10?

For example, some user can execute: `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 ~/mnt/ntfs`
But the same user must not have permission to execute: `sudo mount /dev/sda10 ~/mnt/s10`

Comment: the sudo command let you become root for a while. So, if you are root, shall be no limitations

Comment: @gio900 The point is that one wants to only allow a given user to run a specific command with a specific parameter with root privileges.

Comment: so I cant restrict mount only for /dev/sda2?

Comment: ok, so if you let that user to run a script instead the command, thats limitation will be in the script

Comment: @gio900 how can I make such script?

Comment: eh... just a moment...

Comment: let's have a look if it's ok: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/contributed-scripts.html#USBINST you have to adapt just a bit.

Comment: or, better NOPASSWD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: the trick is to do the script, let it executable, then add the location of it and the correct username in the file /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could create a simple file:

```
 sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides
```

with this directive:

```
 User ALL = NOPASSWD:/sbin/mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /home/User/mnt/ntfs
```

This allow `User` to runs `mount` command with those parameter without entering a password.

Here is [**sudo**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) manual for more details.

Comment: Still problem.  
`sudo -l`: User dmit may run the following commands on mintPC:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /home/dmit/mnt/ntfs
`/bin/mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /home/dmit/mnt/ntfs`
mount: only root can do that

Comment: You should run mount with sudo: "sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /home/dmit/mnt/ntfs" and this will not ask you for password

Comment: You are right. Solved. ty

Answer (score 0):

You can specify arguments in the `sudoers` file, something like this should work:

```
user ALL=(ALL) /sbin/mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /home/user/mnt/ntfs, /sbin/umount /dev/sda2
```