# startup script that needs a user password to execute itself (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, password

Let's say I wanted an automated script to start right after a login prompt. The script, however, needs a user password before it can be executed manually using `sudo 'script'` command from the terminal.

Now, I suppose I could write a script with the needed password and just set it up as one of the startup apps but the thing is I'm trying to avoid putting any sensitive information inside it. And for now, I want this to be an isolated case.

I'm certain there are workarounds but I'm new to Ubuntu, so any help will be most appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have tried that. I created a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` and set the overrides there.

The following line seems to be working just fine:

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD : ALL
```

Problem appears when I try setting it up for a specific script:

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD : /home/user/script
```

Also tried:

```
user host = (root) NOPASSWD : /home/user/script
```

as well as some of the other combinations but nothing works. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Inside the script there is a simple `sudo` command and if I run `bash 'script'`, it always asks me for a user password except in the first example but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I only want override for this script.

I have also changed permissions on the `sudoers.d/override` file as directed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) post.

So I have no idea why it won't work...

Comment: You first say you want to execute `sudo script`. Then you say the script executes some `sudo` command and you run `bash script`. Make up your mind. If you put `user host = (root) NOPASSWD : /home/user/script` in `sudoers`, then you can do `sudo /home/user/script` without needing a password, no more, no less.

Comment: You have a syntax error: the relevant part is (from the linked post) `NOPASSWD:` **not** `NOPASSWD :` (mind the blank!)

Comment: @muru well I haven't been clear enough for which I apologise. It's a script with the line

Comment: with the line that executes another script.

Comment: @guntbert I tried NOPASSWD: without spacing.  Same result.

Comment: @muru you were right. Problem was that when the terminal opens you are already in /home/user/ so I assumed the path is already set for the command.