# intermittent WiFi on 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet

I've just installed Xenial on my home desktop and the internet is very intermittent, showing "there is no internet connection" when I try to load a page. If I disable/enable networking it comes straight back up. Internet works fine on Windows 7. I've updated the rtl8192cu drivers for my Asus Nano USB-N10 N150 WiFi dongle. `nmcli dev` shows that I'm connected to the network but I can't SSH from my laptop to the desktop - "connection refused". `route` shows an empty table.

`ifconfig`:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:da:e9:9d:0c:3e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:234121 (234.1 KB)  TX bytes:234121 (234.1 KB)

wlx382c4a47b381 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:47:b3:81  
          inet addr:192.168.1.80  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3a2c:4aff:fe47:b381/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4606 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5156454 (5.1 MB)  TX bytes:738898 (738.8 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment:

Regarding ssh, have you checked ufw or iptables status?

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

or better yet

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

I suspect this might be your problem. If it's blocked, this is how it's going to look like.

[image]

As for network manager, if restarting works, you could automate it by using [NOPASSWD directive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) and adding it to the startup app so each time you log in, it will restart the service without asking for a password.