# how to edit sudoers file and pass a file which contains list of commands instead of commands list in sudoers file

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, sudo, visudo

I need to edit visudo file to allow users to access certain commands.
If i edit visudo file to add some commands, then i have to edit visudo file very frequently .
Instead of editing visudo file I want to give a file address in that file I want to modify commands based on their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional configuration file, located in the directory `/etc/sudoers.d/`. You should use the same syntax as in `/etc/sudoers/`.

**But note! If you commit a typo in these files, you will not be able to use the `sudo` command anymore, while the typo exists, so you will stuck out of the administrator's privileges.**

> `visudo` parses the sudoers file after the edit and will not save the
>   changes if there is a syntax error - [*read more*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/visudo.8.html).

Here is a great answer related to this question:

- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password/159009#159009)