# Set up sudo so that a particular common user can edit /etc/fstab

Tags: sudo, fstab, su, etc

How can I set up `sudo` so that a particular common user can edit `/etc/fstab`?
I've thought to edit `/etc/sudoers.d` file to do this, but how do we edit `/etc/fstab` in this file?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? And is this the *only* thing, where this user should have elevated permissions? -- And why do you want this? Maybe it is not as secure as you think.

Comment: Read `man sudoers` - it will show you how to allow `sudo` access only to listed commands. BUT all the editors I use have the capability for a "shell escape" (e.g. `vim` and `:!`) that would give access to a `root` shell. In the security biz, that's Game Over. Also, read `man sudoers` about `sudoedit` and the `-e` option.

Comment: Version: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Create simple script, called `editfstab` and located in `/usr/local/bin` (to be accessible as shell command), and make it executable:

```bsh
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nnano /etc/fstab' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/editfstab && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/editfstab
```

Run the command `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/editfstab` and add the following rule as content of the newly created file:

```bsh
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/editfstab
```

At this point, each system user will be able to edit `/etc/fstab`, without password, by the command:

```bsh
sudo editfstab
```

---

You can extend the functionality of `/usr/local/bin/editfstab` by adding a feature to make backup copy before edit:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
nano /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a line in sudoers.d with you favorite editing software in a cmd alias should do the trick :

```
Cmnd_Alias EDITFSTAB = /etc/bin/vim /etc/fstab
username    ALL = (user) EDITFSTAB
```

Be careful, there is a huge risk of escape privilege, maybe you should write a basic shell script to restrict/control fstab modifications WITHOUT using editor (ie "for that modification, press 1" and echo-ing right in fstab).

Comment: woupsie, too slow;)

Comment: Don't use your favourite editor to edit `/etc/sudoers*` files, instead that use `sudo visudo` or `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/<file-name>` . Otherwise any simple typo can lock your system. Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/566421

Comment: Thanks, but it still asks for password after reboot. How can i make this to a specific user and not all of the users in the system?
I tried this: 
username TEST=(TEST:TEST) EDITFSTAB

Comment: Add the nopasswd option : "username ALL=NOPASSWD: EDITFSTAB". And as pa4080 mentionned, use visuel

Comment: Visudo* - typo, on mobile

Comment: I tried the last option, but it still asks for the user password.

Comment: On what line did you add it? Sudoers works in a sequential way, any line with that user/usergroup without the nopaswd option coming after will overwrite the option.