# Create a shortcut on desktop that opens and execute a command with root permission in a terminal

Tags: shortcuts, nethogs

I want to create a shortcut that opens terminal and run `sudo nethogs` command without asking me for root permission.

Comment: Where is your problem? The shortcut or the sudo part?

Comment: sudo part . I want to start the program in terminal without asking me for password and i don't get popup to fill password, it is asked in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways on how to solve this problem:

## Grant `nethogs` the required capabilities

I think the easiest and safest way to do this is to make `nethogs` able to run without root permissions. You can do this by giving it the permissions it is currently temporarily acquiring as root every time you launch it. You can do that with the following command:

`sudo setcap "cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=ep" /usr/sbin/nethogs`

Once you have given `nethogs` these capabilities, it should be able to capture your network traffic without root permissions and you should therefore be able to use it with a shortcut, without having to fill out any credentials.

## Edit `/etc/sudoers`

However, a more general way of solving this sort of problems can be found here [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) Which basically tells you how to safely add `nethogs` or any other command to `/etc/sudoers` to be able to execute it without manually having to type in a password.