# wakeonlan and/or etherwake WITHOUT sudo?

Tags: networking, bash, php, wakeonlan

I'm trying to use wakeonlan to send a magic packet. However, It only works if I use sudo:

```
sudo wakeonlan xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

When I don't use sudo the output says the magic packet has sent, but the server never wakes up. Is there a way to run this command without sudo? I need to do so in order to run the command in a php script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to use `sudo` from php as this article relates:

- [Granting sudo to PHP Script For Running Shell Commands](http://www.bonebrews.com/granting-sudo-to-php/)

Before doing this remember the article's warning:

> Giving sudo to PHP is one of the several ways to execute a shell
>   command from a web interface. It is probably not one of the most
>   secure methods, so I recommend not doing this on a server which has
>   outside (WAN) internet access because of the possibility of malicious
>   code being executed. A person with ill intent could then access your
>   entire network, including any shared files, network attached storage,
>   etc. You need to be careful with this.

### Add user to `/etc/sudoers` file

The article above describes how to setup a user with `sudo` access not needing a password. This Q&A gives other examples:

- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Answer (score 0):

You can add cap_net_raw+ep to the program so it doesn't require sudo. This will also not run the command as root. It permits it to generate arbitrary network packages.

```bsh
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/etherwake /usr/bin/etherwake
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/sbin/etherwake
```

This option might not be available on all systems. Allowing sudo on certain programs without passwords may open up privilege escalation vectors. Abusing raw package generation is a bit harder.