# How do I restrict specific passwordless sudo sub-commands?

Tags: sudo, password

Is there a way to restrict the passwordless sudo commands to a set of "sub-commands".

I am not looking for the answer to [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) I want to know if I it is possible to specify "sub-commands".

For example if I created `/etc/sudoers.d/foo` with contents...

```
bar ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

User `bar` would be able to run *any* `systemctl` commands without a password.

However, if I *only* want `systemctl status <service>` and `systemctl restart <service>` to be run without a password, is there a way to do that?

I tried...

```
bar ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl/restart
```

Just to see if it might work. It does not work.

If this restriction is possible, I would also like to know how to find the absulute path of a "sub-command".

#### Edit

I also tried...

```
$ which systemctl restart
```

But that only output `/bin/systemctl`

Comment: The "sub command" is commonly referred to as an argument or a parameter to the actual command.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks! thats what I would normally call it too, but I looked at the manpage and it kept calling them 'commands' so that threw me off a little.

Comment: Systemd folks like to create their own little world I guess.

Comment: Dumb idea maybe? Create a script with the exact command, let's say `restart-service-x` with content `systemctl restart x`, and give it the proper permissions.

Comment: @guillermochamorro That crossed my mind. However, wrapping a bunch of commands in bash scripts just to handle permissions is not flexible and it is a lot of work. That being said, it is the option I will likely chose if I a more direct method is not possible.

Comment: @guillermochamorro but they will still have access to `systemctl` and if they have a terminal they could type anything manually.The only way I can think of is your own homebrewed security system with each user name and which "subcommand" they are allowed to use.

Comment: You could take a look at how the different commands are handled now. For example, you can run `status` on a system service without sudo, but not `restart`. On some distributions you can run `poweroff` as regular user, while some require root privileges. And the password prompt looks like polkit, so I'd bet there is already a configurable security system for exactly that purpose; you only have to find it.

Comment: There is an [example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Allow_management_of_individual_systemd_units_by_regular_users) in the archlinux wiki. If there is no answer tonight I'll post one.

Comment: @danzel That appears to be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @D.Morell unfortunately, I just read that Ubuntu still ships with policykit 0.105 (for various, complicated reasons), which is the last version before the javascript rules were implemented. (Actually, the switch from pkla based rules to javascript rules seems to be a major reason why debian still maintains 0.105). You can, however, try to at least achieve some of your goals using pkla files.