# How to execute "sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0" from shell script?

Tags: command-line

I want to give access to serial port `/dev/ttyACM0`. How to execute the "`sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0`" command from shell script ?

Comment: you mean `774` or `770`? **Never** give `777` permissions at a folder/file, you would create a huge security breach into your OS

Comment: You create a script to run that command and run it as root.

Comment: If you are asking how to run that command from a shell script without being prompted for a password, see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: There is no need for this: you set the dialout group to include your user. Please keep away from using 777 with chmod.  7[57][05] is for dirs, 6[64][40] is for files. You can set /tmp and cache locations to 777 but then with the sticky bit.

Answer (score 9):

Giving `777` permission to a file is not at all recommended. Since you want to give access to the Serial port, you have to add the user to the `dialout` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
```

Now, no permission will be asked while accessing the serial port.

Note that this solution will also work for uploading code to Arudino boards in Arduino IDE or Serial Monitor in Ubuntu.

Comment: THIS. The correct method is to add the user to the group. That is why dialout exists as a group.