# lubuntu on Aspire One 725 without touchpad

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, acer

I have just bought an 'ACER ASPIRE ONE 725-C7CBB 11.6'' AMD C-70 2GB 320GB RADEON HD7290 LINUX BLUE'. The net book had Linpus installed. I immediately installed lubuntu 13.04 from an external USB DVD-Writer. During the installation the touchpad did not work. I do not have a USB mouse. I managed to complete the installation using the cursor keys. lubuntu 13.04 installed OK but still the touchpad is not working.
I have installed lubuntu in another laptop alongside Windows and the touchpad worked with no problem. Should I install firstly a pirate windows copy to the 725 to get the touchpad drivers and then lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The answer had been given from Mike as the fifth answer in another relevant question the following link:

[Touchpad stopped working on an Acer AspireOne D255E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74964/touchpad-stopped-working-on-an-acer-aspireone-d255e/113708#113708)

By pressing Fn+F7 the Aspire One toggles the activity of the touchpad. I have not used any function key as I had installed lubuntu right after I took the netbook out of the box. It seems that they come from the factory with the touchpad deactivated.