# Touchpad does not work on Acer Aspire V5-121, on

Tags: touchpad, acer, synaptics

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my new Acer Aspire V5-121 Netbook. The first thing I noticed was that the touchpad does not work. It does not recognize clicks or touches. How do I find out what's wrong, and fix it?

I did not find any proprietary drivers for the Touchpad offered by Ubuntu. The package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is already installed.

`xinput list` shows the following:

```
    $ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've already tried the solutions outlined here, for a somewhat similiar issue: [Touchpad stopped working on an Acer AspireOne D255E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74964/touchpad-stopped-working-on-an-acer-aspireone-d255e) . But the solutions outlined here did not help.

Edit: I found a solution. Apparently it was just disabled by the system. Even though I'd turned off the option to disable touchpad when mouse is plugged in, it was disabled for some reason.

Solution: Press Ctrl-Fn-F7.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was solved by pressing the key combo Ctrl-Fn-F7. I had tried the combo Fn-F7 but that did not do anything.